# wordpress website transfer on apache2 but image download button not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, server

I have Transfer my wordpress website from cpanel to ubuntu apache2 but download button not working, i have install all php extension, i am using php 8.2 i am getting this error in pop up shape, (An error while downloading. Please contact system administrator.)  is there any solution?

i have install ububtu and make server carefully but still getting error is there any solution?
i have already install php all extension, all apache config and all files that requies to run wordpress website, but still getting same issue